# Select multiple array from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a search for a property website i'm working on for a friend.
In the Database the property types are named by id numbers, ie: house = 30, flat = 8, terraced =1, and so forth..

How can i retrieve ALL properties from the database when some are detached houses with value of 2 and houses are value of 30 etc :)
It has got me stuck..lol
Here's what i have so far which isn't working...

```
$bedrooms = $_GET['bedrooms'];
$pricefrom = $_GET['pricefrom'];
$priceto = $_GET['priceto'];
$proptype = $_GET['proptype'];

if($proptype == 'house'){
$search_propsubid = array('1,2,3,4,5,6,21,22,23,24,26,27,30');
}elseif($proptype == 'flat'){
$search_propsubid = array('7,8,9,10,11,28,29,44');
}elseif($proptype == 'bungalow'){
$search_propsubid = array('');
}


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE `PROP_SUB_ID`='$search_propsubid' AND `BEDROOMS`='$bedrooms' AND `TRANS_TYPE_ID`='1' HAVING `PRICE` BETWEEN '$pricefrom' AND '$priceto' ORDER BY `UPDATE_DATE` DESC");
```

Thank you for your time i hope someone can point me in the right direction..
Regards
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) array:

```
$search_propsubid = array('1,2,3,4,5,6,21,22,23,24,26,27,30');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $search_propsubid);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE `PROP_SUB_ID` in ($comma_separated) ...
```

Comme back with news if this don't works for you.

Comment: Thank you so very much :D Works a treat, so grateful !!

Comment: @danihp, +'d, I don't want to be on a firefight with you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MySql IN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) comparison operator to select all that match the list of values:

```
$sql = mysql_query("
  SELECT * 
  FROM `properties` 
  WHERE `PROP_SUB_ID` IN (" .implode(",", $search_propsubid). ")
  AND `BEDROOMS`='$bedrooms' 
  AND `TRANS_TYPE_ID`='1' 
  HAVING `PRICE` BETWEEN '$pricefrom' AND '$priceto' 
  ORDER BY `UPDATE_DATE` DESC
");
```

Assuming `$proptype == 'flat'`, the output will be:

```
SELECT *
FROM `properties` 
WHERE `PROP_SUB_ID` IN (7,8,9,10,11,28,29,44) 
...
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply, i'm very grateful you took the time to offer your help :)
Your answer is very similar in nature to the first one which worked perfectly for me.
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Steve, Yap I saw @danihp answer when I've finished publishing my answer... getting the right links and run a test does take some time :) Glad your problem is solved!